# Checking if a number represented by a string is in a certain numeration base

Tags: java, android

I want to implement an algorithm that checks if a number is in a certain numeration base, because numbers from numeration bases bigger than 10 have in their composition digits represented by characters i am forced to use strings.

My ideea of implementation looks like this :

```
private String values = "0123456789ABCDEF";

private boolean check_base(String number,String base) {
    StringBuilder no = new StringBuilder(number);
    while (no.length() != 0) {
        if (no.charAt(number.length() - 1) != '.' && values.indexOf(no.charAt(number.length() - 1)) >=
                values.indexOf(no.charAt(Integer.parseInt(base)))) {
            return false;
        }
        no.deleteCharAt(no.length() - 1);
    }
    return true;
}
```

I don't have any ideea why it crashes my debugging looks like this :

```
private boolean check_base(String number,String base) { base: "16" number: "1.011.0"
    StringBuilder no = new StringBuilder(number); no: "1.011.0" number: "1.011.0"
    while (no.length() != 0) {
```

And after this while loop my application crashes. I think that's because of that `'.'` but that's the reason for having `no.charAt(number.length() - 1) != '.'` condition so i think that isn't a problem or the fact that i use `values.indexOf(no.charAt(number.length() - 1))` but i don't know why this would lead to a crash.

Comment: Do you *really* want to write it yourself? (e.g. for learning purpose). You can also use predefined methods like `Long.valueOf(String s, int radix)`.

Comment: Add System.out.println(no.charAt(number.length() - 1)); --> What does this print?

Comment: What bases are you trying to support?  If it's just base 16, you can use `Integer.parseInt(<string>, <base>)` for integers, or use a regex for decimal values

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle i need this function for a conversion check, i have to do a conversion calculator, also that method `long.valueOf(String s, int radix)` what does return ? I'm new to java and i can't figure out how that method can help me.

Comment: @CătălinMuntean Always see the documentation to know which method is for what. [`Long.valueOf(String s, int radix)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#valueOf(java.lang.String,%20int)) returns a `Long`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, here is your code fixed. Try it and compare it with your version.
You had `no.charAt(number.length() - 1)` which is wrong as `number` doesn't change. You need `no` there, like this `no.charAt(no.length() - 1)`. Also, you had another minor issue.

```
public class Test0030 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(check_base("1.017.0", "8"));
        System.out.println(check_base("1.017.0", "7"));
        System.out.println(check_base("1.01F.0", "16"));
        System.out.println(check_base("1.01F.0", "15"));
    }

    private static String values = "0123456789ABCDEFG";

    private static boolean check_base(String number, String base) {
        StringBuilder no = new StringBuilder(number);
        while (no.length() != 0) {
            if (no.charAt(no.length() - 1) != '.' 
                    && 
                    values.indexOf(no.charAt(no.length() - 1)) >=
                    values.indexOf(values.charAt(Integer.parseInt(base)))) {
                return false;
            }
            no.deleteCharAt(no.length() - 1);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this one works. I didn't saw that i used `number` insted of `no`.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're doing there might be a bit complicated! You could easily iterate over the string, checking if every value is in the `values` string.

**EDIT:** one possibility is to store all the values in a map (the map is initialized in an initializer block here, you might as well do that in the constructor or you fill the map generically!)

```
private Map<Integer, String> values = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
{
    values.put(2,  "01");
    values.put(3,  "012");
    values.put(4,  "0123");
    values.put(5,  "01234");
    values.put(6,  "012345");
    values.put(7,  "0123456");
    values.put(8,  "01234567");
    values.put(9,  "012345678");
    values.put(10, "0123456789");
    values.put(11, "0123456789A");
    values.put(12, "0123456789AB");
    values.put(13, "0123456789ABC");
    values.put(14, "0123456789ABCD");
    values.put(15, "0123456789ABCDE");
    values.put(16, "0123456789ABCDEF");
}

private boolean check_base(String number, String base) {
    int intBase;
    try {
        intBase = Integer.parseInt(base);
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        return false;
    }
    String neededVals = values.get(intBase);
    if (neededVals == null)
        return false;

    for (int i = 0; i < number.length(); i++) {
        char ch = number.charAt(i);
        if (ch != '.' && neededVals.indexOf(ch) == -1)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

The second possibility (but slower) will be to generate the set of chars that are applicable for the base when the method is called.

```
private String generateValues(int base) {
    String ret = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < base; i++) {
        if (i < 10)
            ret += (char)(i+'0');
        else {
            ret += (char)(i-10+'A');
            //ret += (char)(i-10+'a');      // uncomment this line in order to take small letters (a-f) into account!
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

private boolean check_base2(String number, String base) {
    try {
        int intBase = Integer.parseInt(base);
        String values = generateValues(intBase);
        for (int i = 0; i < number.length(); i++) {
            char ch = number.charAt(i);
            if (ch != '.' && values.indexOf(ch) == -1)
                return false;
        }
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This would work perfectly if i want to check if the number is from 16 base, but i want that function to work for every base from 2 to 16.

Comment: @CătălinMuntean allright then you'll have to generate the values string first (I'll provide a small solution for that soon!) / Or you'll save these value strings as constants... I'll show the 2 solutions!

Answer (score 0):

(This should be a comment but I do not have enough place).

In answer to Cătălin Muntean:

`Long.valueOf` converts a `String` to a `Long`. You can optionnally give a base. For example :

```
long result = Long.valueOf("FF", 16);
//result = 255
```

If the method is provided a String which contains unauthorized characters (given the base), it will raise a `NumberFormatException`.

For your check_base, you can use it like this :

```
private boolean check_base(String number,String base) {
  try {
    Long.valueOf(number, base);
    return true;
  } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, is nice to know new things. Don't know why but when i your check_base method my app freezes.